# I lost my tinymce free api key for site now how an i get it back to use it?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins

[this is site](https://tinymce.com)

> And i tried to search on this site for my api key but i am not be find it someone help me to get my api key back

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about retrieving an API key, not about programming. You should contact the company that issued the key.

Comment: but on tinyme.com site u can see that,they have written that we can ask question related to company under tinymce tag now what u would say?

Comment: I would say that tinymce doesn't understand that Stack Overflow is only for programming questions, not company/policy questions. They really shouldn't be outsourcing support this way.

Answer (score 0):

You should sign up using [this link](https://store.ephox.com/signup/)

And then add your API key in your website's `<head>` tag

```
<script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js?apiKey=your_API_key"></script>
```

Comment: yaa thnx i got it .it helped me.

Comment: but y u down voted my question.although it was a valid question

Comment: Stackoverflow users vote the question in terms of quality, for example you used in a wrong way the yellow box and didn't add the error message

Comment: the yellow box is blockquote and it is used to descibing  the problem.my question was not about programming so how can i paste the error msgs.

Comment: okkk thanks you really helped me by giving an answer to my question @ignacio Ara